# php - Check if database table roll count has changed

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to check if the row count of a table in MySQL database has changed. The code I have checked the database for but doesn't store the record of the previous count so I can compare the two.

```
function showapp_count(){

global $wpdb;

$lastappcount = '';

$app_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cb_apps" );

if($app_count !== $lastappcount) {

    $lastappcount = $app_count;

    echo $echoed = $app_count;

    } else{

        echo 'roll count has changed';
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should create a new table with date and app_count, too. So you can have the history of the rows count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
function showapp_count(){

  global $wpdb;

  if (isset($_SESSION['last_count'])) {
    $lastappcount = $_SESSION['last_count'];
  } else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['last_count'] = 0;
  }

  $app_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cb_apps" );

  if($app_count !== $lastappcount) {
     $_SESSION['last_count'] = $app_count;
     echo 'Current count is '.$_SESSION['last_count'];
   } else{
     echo "roll count hasn't changed";
   }
}
```